# Get-Winevent: How to get the correct SecurityDesciptor? (customSD)

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to get the securitydescriptor of the system and application Event Logs to see if it's correct.   That settings is set in the registry key customSD when you change it to a custom one. Problem is, it seems Get-Winevent only return the default settings of channelAccess and ignore any customSD(That behavior happens on Windows 2016 server)

Doing this:

```
$log = Get-WinEvent -ListLog "system"
$log.SecurityDescriptor = $SecurityDescriptor
$log.SaveChanges()
```

will correctly create the customSD registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System and it contains the correct new SDDL string.

But then, running this:

```
$log = Get-WinEvent -ListLog "system"
$log.SecurityDescriptor
```

This will return the default channelAccess SDDL, completely ignoring the customSD key.  Thus, it makes it impossible to verify if the SDDL was applied succesfully.(reading the Reg key is not an option as we want to use this in DSC, and DSC uses the Get-Winevent cmdlet. And yup, it also fails in DSC as the test to verify the change always fails)

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Get-WinEvent isn't providing the updated value, but you could use the [DSC Registry resource](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSDscResources#registry) to check the registry value rather than Get-WinEvent.

Comment: I guess so. That would means not using the  xWinEventLog for setting the Event logs security, but since that doesn't work as it's supposed to, modifying the registry directly would be a workaround.